# statements are skipping when click login event the condition is met

Tags: c#

After checking if `(dt.Rows.Count > 0)` the program skipped `else` `if` and went to else.

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) 

        {

            if (dt.Rows[0][5].ToString() == "Manager")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Manager logedin successfully", "Saleem", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                return;
            }
            else if (dt.Rows[0][5].ToString() == "Supervisor")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Supervisor logedin successfully", "Saleem", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                return;
            }
            else if (dt.Rows[0][5].ToString() == "Cashier")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cashier logedin successfully", "Saleem", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login unsuccessfull", "Saleem", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }

        }
    }
}
```

[image: I made this snippit]

Comment: Perhaps, the condition hasn't been met? Have you checked the value of `dt.Rows.Count`?

Comment: Hi, you may want to check our guideline [tour], and  [ask]. Those are great tools to understand SO, and improve communication skill. For now the '_problem_' you describe looks logic. If the condition of the [if](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else) is not met code will jump to `else`.  The value of  `dt.Rows.Count` is inferior or equals to zero. Perhaps there is no data in the data or this is not the right datasource. We will need an [mcve] for more details

Answer (score 1):

Like Yeldar said in the comment, it seem like your `if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)`  statements condition is not met. This means that `dt.Rows.Count` is less then or equal to 0.
Try setting a breakpoint at that row and look inside (or add to watch) `dt.Rows.Count` so you can see whats in it.

More over:

[Add To Watch](https://kodify.net/csharp/visual-studio/debug-watch/)

[Break points](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to reach the code inside of your outer if statement

`if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)`

if the condition inside of that if statement isn't correct.

Right now, your logic reads as:

```
if dt.Rows.Count > 0
   check if dt.Rows[0][5].ToString() == Manager
   or if dt.Rows[0][5].ToString() == Supervisor
   or if dt.Rows[0][5].ToString() == Cashier
else show login unsuccessful
```

As you can see, the checks will only happen IF dt.Rows.Count > 0

Comment: watch list saying its false if dt.Rows.Count > 0

Comment: This is my SQL Table name UserT: UserID, username, fullname, password,date,usertype.     rows[0][5]